# Fundamentally, what is the difference between redox and acid-base reactions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, redox

For example, consider:

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O -> NH4+ + OH-}$$

Here, the $\ce{NH3}$ is acting as a base (By Lewis theory, it is an electron pair donor).

Why don't we consider this to be a redox (there is a transfer of electrons taking place as $\ce{NH3}$ is acting as an electron donor and $\ce{H2O}$ as an electron acceptor)?

I'm aware that calculation of oxidation states is the best way to figure out if a reaction is redox or not. Then I would like to ask: why exactly do we assign oxidation states according to those rules? Is there an intuitive way to explain why a certain reaction is acid-base and not redox?

Comment: You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math expressions or chem. equations on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: "Fundamentally", there's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to [acid-base reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction)(1), a [redox reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox) is such a reaction, which can be formally divided into two [half-reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-reaction). At least one reactant in such a half-reaction explicitly formally acts as a donor or acceptor of one or more electrons.

$$\ce{Cl2(aq) + 2 Fe^2+(aq) -> 2 Cl-(aq) + 2 Fe^3+(aq)}$$

can be formally divided to:

$$\ce{Cl2(aq) + 2 e- -> 2 Cl-(aq)}$$

$$\ce{2 Fe^2+(aq) -> 2 e- + 2 Fe^3+(aq)}$$

In the example, there was no electron transfer between $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{H2O}$.

[Oxidation states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_state) are nothing more but valence electron inventory with defined formal rules of electron distribution. Their sum does not change during a reaction, due the charge conservation law.

---

(1) A very generalized  Usanovich theory of acids and basis does consider redox reactions as a special case of acid-base reactions. But this theory is not much known nor applied within chemistry community.